# org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:...column: added_by (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to create a bi-directional one to one relationship between two tables. Here are my tables :

```
package com.dietsite.backend.admin.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity(name="UserEntity")
@Table(name = "USERS")
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, name="EMAIL")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "MOBILE")
    private String mobile;
    @Column(name = "OWNER_ID")
    private String ownerId;
    @Column(name = "TRAINER_ID")
    private String trainerId;
    @Column(name = "ADDED_ON")
    private Timestamp addedOn;
    @Column(name = "MODIFIED_ON")
    private Timestamp modifiedOn;
    @Column(name = "ADDED_BY")
    private String addedBy;
    @Column(name = "ADDED_BY")
    private String modifiedBy;
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    List<Role> roles;

    @OneToOne(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            optional = false
    )
    private UserStatisticsEntity userStatisticsEntity;


    public void addUserStatisticsEntity(UserStatisticsEntity userStatisticsEntity) {
        userStatisticsEntity.setUser( this );
        this.userStatisticsEntity = userStatisticsEntity;
    }

    public void removeDetails() {
        if ( userStatisticsEntity != null ) {
            userStatisticsEntity.setUser( null );
            this.userStatisticsEntity = null;
        }
    }



}
```

The child table :

```
package com.dietsite.backend.admin.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity(name = "UserStatisticsEntity")
@Table(name="USER_DETAILS")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserStatisticsEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "HEIGHT")
    private Double height;
    @Column(name = "WEIGHT")
    private Double weight;
    @Column(name = "GOAL_WEIGHT")
    private Double goalWeight;
    @Column(name = "FITNESS_EXPERIENCE")
    private FitnessExperience fitnessExperience;
    @Column(name = "DIET_PREFERENCE")
    private DietPreference dietPreference;
    @Column(name = "ACTIVITY_LEVEL")
    private ActivityLevel activityLevel;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private UserEntity user;
}
```

I'm getting the following error when trying to run the program :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 

'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.dietsite.backend.admin.entity.UserEntity column: added_by (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1771) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at com.dietsite.backend.DietSiteServerApplication.main(DietSiteServerApplication.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.dietsite.backend.admin.entity.UserEntity column: added_by (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1830) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.dietsite.backend.admin.entity.UserEntity column: added_by (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:862) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.17.Final.jar:5.3.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:880) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.17.Final.jar:5.3.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:902) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.17.Final.jar:5.3.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:634) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.17.Final.jar:5.3.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.17.Final.jar:5.3.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:347) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.17.Final.jar:5.3.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:466) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.17.Final.jar:5.3.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1250) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.17.Final.jar:5.3.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried going through numerous articles on fixing the issue and even referred the Hibernate documentation on the same. The current code is how Hibernate has mentioned here :

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations

What am I missing here? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mapped `ADDED_BY` column for two fields in `UserEntity`

```
@Column(name = "ADDED_BY")
private String addedBy;
@Column(name = "ADDED_BY")
private String modifiedBy;
```

You can't map multiple field for same column in entity class.
May be want to do this

```
@Column(name = "ADDED_BY")
private String addedBy;
@Column(name = "MODIFIED_BY")
private String modifiedBy;
```

Comment: Wow. All this time and I couldn't see it. Thank you for the prompt answer.